# How to introduce timeout for my functions?

Tags: ruby

I can use this code to introduce timeout for my functions

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout::timeout(timeout_period) do
  run_some_code
rescue => err
  do_something_with err
  # and maybe the below?
  raise
end
```

How can I create another function `my_timeout` that I can reuse for such purpose? I want to be able to specify that the called function in case of timeout "needs" to be run again.

So then I would call `my_timeout` like `my_timeout('function name',int_how_many_times_to repeat_if times_out)`

- my_timeout("restart_db2_server",5)
- my_timeout("restart_eduserver",3)
- my_timeout("run_test",0)

I use `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]`on Windows7

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_timeout repeat_n_times, timeout_period, &block
  Timeout::timeout timeout_period, &block
rescue Timeout::Error => timeout_error
  repeat_n_times -= 1

  if repeat_n_times > 0
    retry
  else
    raise timeout_error
  end
end

# Example

# execute the block with a timeout of 30 and repeat up to 5 times
my_timeout 5, 30 do
  # do the heavy work
end
```

Comment: How would I call such function?

Comment: So I do call it `my_timeout (5,100) do restart_db2_server() end`

Comment: Then, why do I pass `&block` to the my_timeout function?

Comment: And why aren't `()` used in the definition? `my_timeout (repeat_n_times, timeout_period, &block)`

Comment: Instead of doing it recursively, you can use the `retry` keyword here.

Comment: You are not "passing" `&block` to the function, you define `my_timeout` to take a block/proc as argument/parameter. And parentheses are not mandatory neither in function definitions nor function calls...